# How to import the Mysql database using Java

Tags: java, mysql

I need to import my database using Java. I am using Wamp and SQL version 5.7.19. I am trying to get the backup of my database when a user clicks on the export button and save the .sql file to the path selected by the user. Can Somebody Tell me what is the issue

```
   JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
   fc.showOpenDialog(this);
   String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());

    try {
        File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
        path = f.getAbsolutePath();
        path = path.replace('\\', '/');
        path = path+"_"+date+ ".sql";
        jTextField2.setText(path);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Process p = null;
    try {

        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        p = runtime.exec("c:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.19/bin/mysqldump -u root - proot --add-drop-database -B dbName -r "
                    + jTextField2.getText() + path + ".sql");

        int processComplete = p.waitFor();

        if (processComplete == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Backup created successfully");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Could not create the backup   !!!");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I can’t really tell the issue with the information provided. Please specify the expected behaviour and precisely how observed behaviour differs. Quote any error message or stacktrace verbatim. Thereby you’ll help us help you.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the outdated and troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. Better and simpler to use `String date = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t tested, but I think your problem is here:

```
                + jTextField2.getText() + path + ".sql");
```

As I read the code, the text field contains the path, and and the `path` variable too, so you get it twice in the command string. You also got `".sql"` *three* times in total since you’ve already appended it to `path` before filling it into the text field. I suggest just:

```
                + path);
```

Comment: I have changed to  p= runtime.exec("C:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.19/bin/mysqldump -uroot -proot --add-drop-database -B erp -r" +path);
nt processComplete = p.waitFor();
            
            if (processComplete==0) {
                jLabel2.setText("Restored Succuss");
                
            }else{
                jLabel2.setText("Can't Create Backup");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

But it shows me can't create backup. I am quite new to Java

Comment: Can you run the command from the command line/DOS prompt? Are you sure the command is exactly the same? Watch for missing spaces and such. What is `-r`? I don’t see it in [the `mysqldump` documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html). What is the value of `processComplete`? This should be the value returned from `mysqldump`.

Comment: I can use the same command from the command line but with some different syntax ie.

c:\mysqldump -uroot -proot dbname > " C:\location\backup.sql"  while using the mentioned command A file is created in the location with the name backup.sql fro the database dbname and username & Password is root. But I can use this command in Java String so I checked on internet and got the command mentioned in the actual question comment . According to that -r is used to give the location where the backup need to saved. ProcessComplete is null and rest waitfor() will give a int in ProcessComplete

Comment: My bad, the doc page I linked to does give --result-file=file_name, -r file_name as a command line option. There’s a space between `-r` and the file name, I think you should make sure that you have that too.

Comment: I do have space in between `-r` and filename. My exact value of p is
`p = runtime.exec("c:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.19/bin/mysqldump -u root - proot --add-drop-database -B dbName -r "+ path );`
 I know I am doing some silly mistake but can't figure it out. I must say thanks to you for your concern. Being a newbie It means a lot hope we will solve this issue.

Comment: I think I’d try to get the same command string to work in both the DOS prompt and in Java. Or at least as close as possible. I think this will give the best chance of spotting problems.

Comment: I tried this command to bypass via Java but it is not working. You try from your end may be there is something which I am missing. This is the command for Dos and it is working fine. `c:\mysqldump -uroot -proot dbname > " C:\location\backup.sql" `

Comment: Haven’t got MySQL installed, so am not trying here.

Comment: Oh anyway you were of great help. Thanks @Ole